# Oracle query to select distinct Value based on another column value

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider the below sample table:

```
ID    Value
123   ABC
456   DEF
456   ABC
```

I want the select query result as below:

```
ID    Value
123   ABC
456   DEF
```

Note: ID has only 2 different values - "123" and "456". Selection should be based on Column "ID". If value "123" is present, the corresponding data from "Value" column has to be selected. If not "456" ID should be retrieved.

Comment: post the actual ID value if it is a string

Comment: What do you mean by *" If value "123" is present* ? with respect to what ? You said Id only has 123 or 456, so it should be present isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

simple group by will help you to get the desired result

```
select min(id), value
from table
group by value
```

Comment: Sorry forget to mention that ID is not a number. It is a string. So min(id) is not helpful.

Comment: @Viswa cast it as a numeric use TO_NUMBER

Comment: min function can be applied not only for numbers.

Comment: min function will not work if 123 is yyy and 456 is xxx

Comment: @psaraj12 . . . Then use `max()`.  It is only possible to answer the question that is asked, and this seems like this simplest answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's why I have asked the actual ID value to OP and given a generic solution

Comment: you are letting the data decide min or max to be used which is not good design

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below if ID is a string like 456 is 'xxx' and 123 is 'yyy' [The SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5967c/1)

```
WITH tt1 
     AS (SELECT Decode(id, '123', 1, 
                           2) order1, 
                id, 
                value1 
         FROM   tt), 
     tt2 
     AS (SELECT Min(order1) order1, 
                value1 
         FROM   tt1 
         GROUP  BY value1) 
SELECT tt1.id, 
       tt1.value1 
FROM   tt2, 
       tt1 
WHERE  tt1.value1 = tt2.value1 
       AND tt1.order1 = tt2.order1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this:

```
    select min(id) as id,
           Value 
    from table
    group by  Value, id
```